# How to change formatting of \part in a .cls file?

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, parts, report

I'm using an external `.cls` file, which is based on the report.cls template. I need to change the formatting of the top-level parts (i.e. `\part` objects) in the table of contents, and on the `\part` pages. In particular,

- On the table of contents, I need the `\part` entries to be centered, all-caps, no page number, and start with the word "PART" e.g. "PART I: FOO," "PART II: BAR"
- On the `\part` pages within the document, I need to turn off page numbering in the footer.

Currently, in the `.cls` file, the `\tableofcontents` command is:

```
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{%
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \normalsize
    \chapter*{\contentsname
        \@mkboth{%
           \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}%
    {\hfill \textbf{Page}\par}%
    {\hyphenpenalty=\umthesis@listhyphenpenalty\@starttoc{toc}}%
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
    }
```

As for `\part` formatting, I don't see any commands in the `.cls` file for it.

I think these are straightforward changes for you TeX experts out there, but as a noob with a deadline, I'm not making much headway.  Any help appreciated!

Comment: Look for `\@part`

Comment: @egreg: nothing like `\@part` in the .cls file either, thanks.

Comment: @limist You need to look at the `report.cls` file ! line 304 : `\def\@part[#1]#2{% ....`

Comment: Without seeing the `.cls` file the task is quite similar to divination.

Comment: @egreg the class is based on report.cls

Comment: Perhaps i don't understand :  "based in the report template".

Comment: Is this a University of Michigan class file? The class is a total redefinition of the standard class and does not provide any definitions for Part. Are you sure you want to do this? As obviously you will not be following the University's standard thesis layout. If you do you need to get a copy of `book.cls` and copy the relevant sections, they are rather long.

Comment: @Altermundus: thanks, further enlightenment would be appreciated. :)

Comment: @Yiannis: no, it's another university's class file.

Comment: @limist Then it has the same disease:) In your code the prefix  states  `\umthesis` that made me think is from there. You need to give a link.

Comment: Someone (i.e., faculty or staff) at that other university needs to take responsibility for the class file. Also, I'm going to guess [this](https://github.com/umasscs/umthesis) might be the class file in question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the class doesn't define `\part` and the command is usable, then there is somewhere near the beginning of the class file the command `\LoadClass` and, from what you're reporting, the base class should be `report`.

So the definition to modify can be found in `report.cls`; the following should do what you're looking for:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@part[#1]#2{%
  \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
    \refstepcounter{part}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{%
      \MakeUppercase{Part \thepart: #1}}%
  \else
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}%
  \fi
  \markboth{}{}%
  {\centering
   \interlinepenalty \@M
   \normalfont
   \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
     \huge\bfseries \partname\nobreakspace\thepart
     \par
     \vskip 20\p@
   \fi
   \Huge \bfseries #2\par}%
  \@endpart}
\def\@endpart{%
   \thispagestyle{empty}%
   \vfil\newpage
   \if@twoside
     \if@openright
       \null
       \thispagestyle{empty}%
       \newpage
     \fi
   \fi
   \if@tempswa
     \twocolumn
   \fi}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thanks - which file should this code go into please?

Comment: @limist Put it in your preamble, before `\begin{document}`.

Comment: Thank you; some additional changes were needed but the general approach works.